# TinyOS CC2420ReceiveP

Tags: crc, tinyos

I want to hold onto packets that fail the crc check. To do this I have commented out a section of the CC2420RecieveP readDone function that checks the msb bit of the LQI byte in the received buffer.

I think this is working,

However, once I receive the packet in my own receive function I send it through the serial component (not just the payload, I copy the whole received radio packet into the payload area of the serial packet).
When I use the program Listen, it seems that the crc bool value is not there (only the LQI and RSSI) even though the crc is clearly copied into the bufPTR in the function receiveDone_task.

:(

Help!

Mike.

Answer (score 2):

i was only copying the first 28 bytes (not the header plus a 28 byte payload plus the metadata)

:P